# pandas split list into columns with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a string list:

```
content
01/09/15, 10:07 - message1
01/09/15, 10:32 - message2
01/09/15, 10:44 - message3
```

I want a data frame, like:

```
     date                message
01/09/15, 10:07          message1
01/09/15, 10:32          message2
01/09/15, 10:44          message3
```

Considering the fact that all my strings in the list starts in that format, I can just split by `-`, but I rather look for a smarter way to do so.

```
history = pd.DataFrame([line.split(" - ", 1) for line in content], columns=['date', 'message'])
```

(I'll convert the date to date time afterwards)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` - where named groups can become column names

```
In [5827]: df['content'].str.extract('(?P<date>[\s\S]+) - (?P<message>[\s\S]+)', 
                                     expand=True)
Out[5827]:
              date   message
0  01/09/15, 10:07  message1
1  01/09/15, 10:32  message2
2  01/09/15, 10:44  message3
```

---

Details

```
In [5828]: df
Out[5828]:
                      content
0  01/09/15, 10:07 - message1
1  01/09/15, 10:32 - message2
2  01/09/15, 10:44 - message3
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! By the way, if the columns are being extracted so they can be tacked on to the existing dataframe, we can just follow this up with ```df = pd.concat([df, df_e], axis=1)``` where df_e is the extracted dataframe.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `\s+-\s+` - `\s+` is one or more whitespaces:

```
df[['date','message']] = df['content'].str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True)
print (df)
                      content             date   message
0  01/09/15, 10:07 - message1  01/09/15, 10:07  message1
1  01/09/15, 10:32 - message2  01/09/15, 10:32  message2
2  01/09/15, 10:44 - message3  01/09/15, 10:44  message3
```

If need remove `content` column add [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df[['date','message']] = df.pop('content').str.split('\s+-\s+', expand=True)

print (df)
              date   message
0  01/09/15, 10:07  message1
1  01/09/15, 10:32  message2
2  01/09/15, 10:44  message3
```