# Parse phone number and string into new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a list of addresses in a single column `address`, how would I go about parsing the phone number and restaurant category into new columns? My dataframe looks like this

```
  address
0 Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310-246-1501 Steakhouses                                                                    
1 Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 818-762-1221 Delis                                                                                             
2 Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air 310-472-1211 French Bistro
```

where I want to get

```
  address | phone_number | category
0 Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles | 310-246-1501 | Steakhouses                                                                    
1 Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City | 818-762-1221 | Delis                                                                                             
2 Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air | 310-472-1211 | French Bistro
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the address always at the end, like you've shown in your example?

Comment: tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929029/10197418) method? the `regex` could e.g. be `'[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Regex with `str.extract`.

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'address':["Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310-246-1501 Steakhouses", 
                              "Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 818-762-1221 Delis",
                              "Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air 310-472-1211 French Bistro"]})
df[["address", "phone_number", "category"]] = df["address"].str.extract(r"(?P<address>.*?)(?P<phone_number>\b\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}\b)(?P<category>.*$)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             address  phone_number  \
0  Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Bl...  310-246-1501   
1        Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City   818-762-1221   
2        Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air   310-472-1211   

         category  
0     Steakhouses  
1           Delis  
2   French Bistro
```

**Note:**: Assuming the content of address is always `address--phone_number--category`

Answer (score 1):

#### Using `str.extract` and `str.split`:

1. We extract the pattern `numbers dash numbers dash numbers` for `phone_number`
2. We split on the pattern `3 numbers followed by a space` and grab the part after it for `category`. We use `positive lookbehind` for this, which is `?<=` in regex

```
df['phone_number'] = df['address'].str.extract('(\d+-\d+-\d+)')
df['category'] = df['address'].str.split('(?<=\d{3})\s').str[-1]
```

**Output**

```
                                                                                  address  phone_number       category
0  Arnie Morton's of Chicago 435 S. La Cienega Blvd. Los Angeles 310-246-1501 Steakhouses  310-246-1501    Steakhouses
1                           Art's Deli 12224 Ventura Blvd. Studio City 818-762-1221 Delis  818-762-1221          Delis
2                   Bel-Air Hotel 701 Stone Canyon Rd. Bel Air 310-472-1211 French Bistro  310-472-1211  French Bistro
```